# Converting a regular json file to a parent-child hierarchical json as used by d3 flare.json

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have a json file with the following structure:

```
  {
    "a": "b",
    "c": "d",
    "e": {
      "f": "g",
      "h": "i"
    }
  }
```

I would like it to have the following structure:

```
  {
    "name": "Root",
    "parent": "null",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "a",
        "parent": "Root",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "b",
            "parent": "a"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "c",
        "parent": "Root",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "d",
            "parent": "d"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "e",
        "parent": "Root",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "f",
            "parent": "e",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "g",
                "parent": "f"
              },
              {
                "name": "h",
                "parent": "e",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "name": "i",
                    "parent": "h"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

I would like to have a parent-children hierarchy relationship so that it would be easier to draw a collapsible-tree diagram with nodes.Please forgive if the indentation is not proper.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) here.

Comment: Why the `parent` nodes?  They don't add any information not already in the structure.

Comment: What have you tried? You'll have to iterate through the keys and create your own resultant json, probably using some sort of recursion.

Comment: why do you have an outer array of data?

Comment: loop your data and build the new object, theres no really any auto-magic way to do this, but as others have pointed out consider redesigning your data model before coding.

Comment: @ScottSauyet That is the final json file needed. It is fine without "parent". Atleast "name" and "children" are needed

Comment: @NinaScholz Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: We still need to see your attempt.  SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I tried converting it into a nested form using d3.nest, but the result was not as expected. Same with the case of converting it into a tabular form or a comma delimited form and then back to a nested json. The problem with that approach is that it does not take into account the varying number of children for every parent

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. I'll keep in mind putting my attempt/research in the question while posting. Sorry for the bad editing. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a recursive approach by using the object and a parent value.

For getting the wanted style with `Root` element, you need to hand over a new object which follows the same building rule than the inner objects of the given data.

> ```
> {
>     Root: data[0]
> }
> ```

```js
const
    getObjects = (o, parent) =>
        o && typeof o === 'object'
            ? Object.entries(o).map(([name, v]) => ({ name, parent, children: getObjects(v, name) }))
            : [{ name: o, parent }];

var data = [{ a: "b", c: "d", e: { f: "g", h: "i" } }],
    result = getObjects({ Root: data[0] }, 'null');

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possibility:

```js
const treeify = (orig) => Object.entries(orig).map(
  ([k, v]) => (Object.assign({name: k}, typeof v == 'object'
    ? {children: treeify(v)} 
    : {children: {name: v}}
  ))
)
const convert = (orig) => ({name: 'Root', children: treeify(orig)})

const orig = {"a": "b", "c": "d", "e": {"f": "g", "h": "i"}}

console.log(convert(orig))
```

`treeify` handles the heavy lifting, and `convert` is a simple wrapper that adds the `Root` node.  Note that there is no attempt to create `parent` nodes, as those, according to the comments, are not necessary.

#### Update

The clarity of the answer from Nina Scholz, which does supply a parent (I thought it would be much more difficult!) suggests an alternative to this version to also include it.  Even without the parents, I like this version of `convert` better:

```js
const treeify = (orig, parent) => Object.entries(orig).map(
  ([k, v]) => (Object.assign({name: k, parent}, typeof v == 'object' 
    ? {children: treeify(v, k)} 
    : {children: {name: v, parent: k}}
  ))
)

const convert = (orig) => treeify({Root: orig}, 'null')[0]

const orig = {"a": "b", "c": "d", "e": {"f": "g", "h": "i"}}
console.log(convert(orig))
```