# Converting separate data frames to a JSON file for a tidy tree chart

Tags: r, json, d3.js

I did not know how to store complex tidy tree data in excel, so I decided to store data for each level in a sheet.
For a simple example, consider the two following dataframes.

[image]

[image]

#### for making a tidy tree chart from this dataframes I have tried the following step:

Data

```r
dim_data <- structure(list(dim1 = c("sub1", "sub2", "sub3"), dim2 = c("sub4", 
"sub5", NA)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

sub_data <- structure(list(sub1 = c("a", "b", "c"), sub2 = c("d", "f", NA
), sub3 = c("e", "h", NA), sub4 = c("i", "g", NA), sub5 = c("k", 
"p", NA)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Code:

```r
## Function to make each column a list and remove `na`.

list_remove_na <- function(x){
  x <- lapply(x, as.list)
  x <- sapply(x, function(x) x[!is.na(x)])
  x <- sapply(x, unlist)
  return(x)

sub_list <- list_remove_na(sub_data)
attach(sub_list)
data_list <- list_remove_na(dim_data)

## Making final list 
integrate <- function(x){sapply(x, function(x){ x = get(x)},simplify = F)} 
final_list <- sapply(data_list, integrate, simplify = F)
```

Final list:

```r
final_list 

$dim1
$dim1$sub1
[1] "a" "b" "c"

$dim1$sub2
[1] "d" "f"

$dim1$sub3
[1] "e" "h"


$dim2
$dim2$sub4
[1] "i" "g"

$dim2$sub5
[1] "k" "p"
```

Converting the `final list` to `JSON`

```r
library(rjson)
jdata <-toJSON(final_list, indent=1, method="C")
write(jdata, file =  "data.json")
```

JSON File:

```
{
 "dim1":{
  "sub1":[
"a",
"b",
"c"
  ],
  "sub2":[
"d",
"f"
  ],
  "sub3":[
"e",
"h"
  ]
 },
 "dim2":{
  "sub4":[
"i",
"g"
  ],
  "sub5":[
"k",
"p"
  ]
 }
}
```

Then Using following function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53050116/converting-a-regular-json-file-to-a-parent-child-hierarchical-json-as-used-by-d3) to make a `Parents and children JSON data`:

```js
const treeify = (orig, parent) => Object.entries(orig).map(
  ([k, v]) => (Object.assign({name: k, parent}, typeof v == 'object' 
    ? {children: treeify(v, k)} 
    : {children: {name: v, parent: k}}
  ))
)

const convert = (orig) => treeify({Root: orig}, 'null')[0]

const orig = 
{
 "dim1":{
  "sub1":[
"a",
"b",
"c"
  ],
  "sub2":[
"d",
"f"
  ],
  "sub3":[
"e",
"h"
  ]
 },
 "dim2":{
  "sub4":[
"i",
"g"
  ],
  "sub5":[
"k",
"p"
  ]
 }
}



console.log(convert(orig))
```

Result:

```
{
  "name": "Root",
  "parent": "null",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "dim1",
      "parent": "Root",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "sub1",
          "parent": "dim1",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "0",
              "parent": "sub1",
              "children": {
                "name": "a",
                "parent": "0"
              }
            },
            {
              "name": "1",
              "parent": "sub1",
              "children": {
                "name": "b",
                "parent": "1"
              }
            },
            {
              "name": "2",
              "parent": "sub1",
              "children": {
                "name": "c",
                "parent": "2"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "sub2",
          "parent": "dim1",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "0",
              "parent": "sub2",
              "children": {
                "name": "d",
                "parent": "0"
              }
            },
            {
              "name": "1",
              "parent": "sub2",
              "children": {
                "name": "f",
                "parent": "1"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "sub3",
          "parent": "dim1",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "0",
              "parent": "sub3",
              "children": {
                "name": "e",
                "parent": "0"
              }
            },
            {
              "name": "1",
              "parent": "sub3",
              "children": {
                "name": "h",
                "parent": "1"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "dim2",
      "parent": "Root",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "sub4",
          "parent": "dim2",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "0",
              "parent": "sub4",
              "children": {
                "name": "i",
                "parent": "0"
              }
            },
            {
              "name": "1",
              "parent": "sub4",
              "children": {
                "name": "g",
                "parent": "1"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "sub5",
          "parent": "dim2",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "0",
              "parent": "sub5",
              "children": {
                "name": "k",
                "parent": "0"
              }
            },
            {
              "name": "1",
              "parent": "sub5",
              "children": {
                "name": "p",
                "parent": "1"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

#### I do not know where `"name": "0"` is come from!!!

And tidy tree from [here](http://www.d3noob.org/2014/01/tree-diagrams-in-d3js_11.html)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Collapsible Tree Example</title>

<style>

 .node circle {
   fill: #fff;
   stroke: steelblue;
   stroke-width: 3px;
 }

 .node text { font: 12px sans-serif; }

 .link {
   fill: none;
   stroke: #ccc;
   stroke-width: 2px;
 }
 
</style>

  </head>

  <body>

<!-- load the d3.js library --> 
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
 
<script>

var treeData = [
  {
  "name": "Root",
  "parent": "null",
  "children": [
{
  "name": "dim1",
  "parent": "Root",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "sub1",
      "parent": "dim1",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "0",
          "parent": "sub1",
          "children": {
            "name": "a",
            "parent": "0"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "1",
          "parent": "sub1",
          "children": {
            "name": "b",
            "parent": "1"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "2",
          "parent": "sub1",
          "children": {
            "name": "c",
            "parent": "2"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "sub2",
      "parent": "dim1",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "0",
          "parent": "sub2",
          "children": {
            "name": "d",
            "parent": "0"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "1",
          "parent": "sub2",
          "children": {
            "name": "f",
            "parent": "1"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "sub3",
      "parent": "dim1",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "0",
          "parent": "sub3",
          "children": {
            "name": "e",
            "parent": "0"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "1",
          "parent": "sub3",
          "children": {
            "name": "h",
            "parent": "1"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
{
  "name": "dim2",
  "parent": "Root",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "sub4",
      "parent": "dim2",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "0",
          "parent": "sub4",
          "children": {
            "name": "i",
            "parent": "0"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "1",
          "parent": "sub4",
          "children": {
            "name": "g",
            "parent": "1"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "sub5",
      "parent": "dim2",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "0",
          "parent": "sub5",
          "children": {
            "name": "k",
            "parent": "0"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "1",
          "parent": "sub5",
          "children": {
            "name": "p",
            "parent": "1"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
  ]
}
];

// ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
 width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
 height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
 
var i = 0;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
 .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
 .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
 .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
 .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

root = treeData[0];
  
update(root);

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
   links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

  // Declare the nodesâ€¦
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
   .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter the nodes.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
   .attr("class", "node")
   .attr("transform", function(d) { 
return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
   .attr("r", 10)
   .style("fill", "#fff");

  nodeEnter.append("text")
   .attr("x", function(d) { 
return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13; })
   .attr("dy", ".35em")
   .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { 
return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
   .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
   .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Declare the linksâ€¦
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
   .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter the links.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
   .attr("class", "link")
   .attr("d", diagonal);

}

</script>
 
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

#### The last level nodes are wrong!!!

#### Anybody has suggestions for fixing the problems or alternative solutions in `R` or `Python`?

#### Is there `R` or `Python` function to convert `raw JSON` to `hierarchical parent and children Json`?

#### How can I rewrite the `R` function to convert more than two dataframes (scaling it)?

**I have limited knowledge about`javascript` and `JSON`

Answer (score 2):

I'll provide a solution for your case of two data frames, but I'd like to find out whether you can store the data in a different format (which can be expanded to more dimensions). I'll illustrate below what I mean.

First, I'll load two packages. The first one (`data.table`) will help with the data.wrangling, whereas the second (`collapsibleTree`) will help with the tree visualization:

```
# Load packages
library(data.table)
library(collapsibleTree)
```

Next I convert the datasets to `data.table` as I want to re-format them:

```
# Convert datasets to data.table format
setDT(sub_data)
setDT(dim_data)
```

I now convert them to (what is called) 'long' format by using the `melt` function:

```
# Convert to long format
sub_data_2 = melt.data.table(sub_data, measure.vars = colnames(sub_data))
dim_data_2 = melt.data.table(dim_data, measure.vars = colnames(dim_data))
```

At this point, I have `sub_data_2`:

```
    variable value
 1:     sub1     a
 2:     sub1     b
 3:     sub1     c
 4:     sub2     d
 5:     sub2     f
 6:     sub2  <NA>
 7:     sub3     e
 8:     sub3     h
 9:     sub3  <NA>
10:     sub4     i
11:     sub4     g
12:     sub4  <NA>
13:     sub5     k
14:     sub5     p
15:     sub5  <NA>
```

and `dim_data_2`:

```
   variable value
1:     dim1  sub1
2:     dim1  sub2
3:     dim1  sub3
4:     dim2  sub4
5:     dim2  sub5
6:     dim2  <NA>
```

Next, we merge them:

```
# Merge
merged = merge(dim_data_2, sub_data_2, by.x = "value", by.y = "variable")
```

Then do some clean up by renaming columns, and removing those rows with `NA` entries:

```
# Cleanup
setnames(merged, colnames(merged), c("sub", "dim", "value"))
merged_2 = merged[complete.cases(merged),]
```

This is the format I was referring to above:

```
    sub  dim value
 1: sub1 dim1     a
 2: sub1 dim1     b
 3: sub1 dim1     c
 4: sub2 dim1     d
 5: sub2 dim1     f
 6: sub3 dim1     e
 7: sub3 dim1     h
 8: sub4 dim2     i
 9: sub4 dim2     g
10: sub5 dim2     k
11: sub5 dim2     p
```

**Is it possible for you to save in this format?** Most of what I've done so far is data wrangling. As you will see below, once I have this format, tree plotting is one line of code:

```
collapsibleTree(merged_2, c("dim", "sub", "value"), collapsed = F)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I skimmed the `collapsibleTree` package source and found the `data.tree` package. I am working on it